# Multiple freezing after Ubuntu 22.04 installation

Tags: boot, uefi, freeze, usb-installation, grub-legacy

I just finished installing Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell Latitude E7250. I have tried installation multiple times with different options (Legacy, UEFI) on this computer, but every time after the installation is finished, the system crashes very often.

I have installed the same version on more than 5 machines and they all work fine, but the issue is persistent in this one. I just finished installing with UEFI settings and after several crashes every time I open Firefox I am at this window.

[image]